# Show the following distributional equation: $v \delta'=v(0) \delta' - v'(0) \delta$ for $v \in C^\infty$

Tags: distribution-theory

Originally this was an example stated in class but without proof. When trying to prove it I got a different result for the expression $v \delta'$. Here I presented my calculations which were approved in the comments. In the end it was pointed out by my professor that there was a typo in class. So I changed the question and included my computations as an answer. For the case if some person is stumbles upon this question and is interested in an answer.

---

As in the title stated I want to show that

> $$v \delta'=v(0) \delta' - v'(0) \delta$$

in distributional sense where $v \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\delta \in \mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ is the Dirac Delta distribution which is defined by $$\langle \delta, \phi \rangle=\phi(0) \quad \forall \phi \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega).$$ Hence we have for the derivative of the Dirac Delta distributional $$\langle \delta',\phi\rangle=-\langle\delta,\phi'\rangle=-\phi'(0).$$

From this we should be able to prove the above relation which involves $\delta'$.

Comment: Observe that the question is poorly formulated, in the sense that $v(0) \delta$ doesn't have any mathematical sense

Comment: It is meant in distributional sense, i.e. we interpret it as $<v(0) \delta, \phi>=<\delta,v(0) \phi>=v(0) \phi(0)$ for all $\phi \in C_0^\infty$. Then it should make sense, I think.

Comment: Your computations looks fine to me.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your comment. I also didn't notice a mistake, so I will accept that it should be typo in the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have$$\begin{aligned} \langle v \delta', \phi \rangle =\langle \delta',v \phi \rangle=-\langle\delta, (v \phi)'\rangle &=-(v\phi)'(0)
\\ &=-v(0) \phi'(0)-v'(0) \phi(0) 
\\ &=v(0) \langle\delta',\phi\rangle-v'(0)\langle\delta,\phi\rangle
\\ &=\langle v(0)\delta'-v'(0)\delta, \phi\rangle \end{aligned}$$
for all test function $\phi \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega)$ and hence
$$v\delta'=v(0) \delta' - v'(0) \delta.$$