# How to expand $\langle (f \delta)', \phi \rangle$?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

My question is the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2166668/693799), but for the Dirac delta function. I did find several Math SE posts and one Wikipedia article on seemingly the same issue, but upon a closer inspection they all are dealing with $\langle f \delta ', \phi \rangle$ (see, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2707894/693799)), whereas I'm interested in the case when $f$ is within the parentheses with Dirac delta.

I have attempted to expand it the two ways. And in both cases I've got zeros.

***The first way***.

$$\langle (f \delta)', \phi \rangle = - \langle (f \delta), \phi ' \rangle = - \langle \delta, (f \phi ' ) \rangle = - (f \phi ' ) \rvert_{t=0} = -f(0) \phi(0)' $$

Then I had a look at the first picture on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). The picture represents a test function. And it is absolutely clear that its derivative at 0 is 0. And I concluded that:

$$-f(0) \phi(0)' = 0$$

***The second way***.

$$\langle (f \delta)', \phi \rangle = - \langle (f \delta), \phi ' \rangle = - \langle \delta, (f \phi ' ) \rangle = - \langle \delta, ((f \phi)' - f' \phi) \rangle = - \langle \delta, (f \phi)' \rangle + \langle \delta, (f' \phi) \rangle = - \langle \delta, (f' \phi + f \phi ') \rangle + (f' \phi) \rvert_{t=0} = - \langle \delta,(f' \phi) \rangle - \langle \delta,(f \phi ') \rangle + f'(0) \phi(0) = -(f' \phi) \rvert_{t=0} - (f \phi ') \rvert_{t=0} + f'(0) \phi(0) = -f(0)' \phi(0) - f(0) \phi(0)' + f'(0) \phi(0) = - f(0) \phi(0)'$$

And using the same argument as above, I conclude that $$ -f(0) \phi(0)' = 0$$

Here are my questions.

1. I'm wondering if my two derivations are correct.
2. Derivative of the test function at zero is so obviously zero, yet I haven't encountered examples where it would be equalized to zero. Thus, I'm slightly worried about equating it to zero. Is it ok to do it? Is there an example of a physical problem where it is normally done?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked is for  *bump* functions. Test functions are simply $C_c^\infty(X)$, and they don't have a prescribed value nor derivative at zero nor any other point.

Comment: This made me laugh. Test functions can have non-zero derivative at $0$. If you type table on Wikipedia and you see an image of a wood table, will you conclude that all the tables are made of wood?

Comment: I see, thank you @MartinArgerami and LL 3.14. Can you give your opinions on the derivations themselves, please? To clarify. I'm not a mathematician. I can show every equality in my derivations is correct by converting the distributions to the integrals. But that's just wrong. I noticed mathematicians use properties of linear operators instead. Thus, I can tell that since $\delta$ is linear, then the following is true: $\delta[a+b]=\delta[a]+\delta[b]$. But I'm not sure about the rest of my steps. I'm asking you if you can be so kind to check my derivations steps on "mathematical rigor" please.

Comment: The manipulations look fine, though you never said where you work, what space. But the question is, what are you trying to achieve? In typical manipulations with weak derivatives the goal is to get a new expression for your function; this requires that in the end you have an expression of the form $\langle *,\phi\rangle$ (because if $\langle g,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\phi\rangle$ you conclude that $f=g$). In this case you seem to be proving that the weak derivative of $f\delta$ is the operator $\phi\longmapsto -f(0)\phi'(0)$; not sure what you can make of that.

Comment: Thank you @MartinArgerami. I'm trying to do what's done in the post I cited first in my question: to see if it is possible to represent the derivative of $\delta$ via some function of $\delta$. I see now, that's impossible. I wanted a mathematician's confirmation for that. I have to contend with $\langle (f \delta)', \phi \rangle=-f(0)\langle \delta, \phi ' \rangle$. This entire question is the part of my own research into the Navier-Stoke's equation. I have never liked how the two-phase N-S was done and decided to try and do it how I think it should be done in order to understand it better.